# how to avoid chaining my checkbox to default in a asp.net which autoreloads?

Tags: asp.net

i have a problem with my asp.net site.

i have a checkbox on this site, which is per default checked.
then i have a javascript code which reloads the page every minute.

now the problem:
when i uncheck the checkbox and the page reloads, it gets checked again.
but i want to avoid this, i want the checkbox to have the same checked/unchecked property as before the reload.

how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to inform your server(again with javascript) when the state of the checkbox changes.

This information will be saved (i.e. in viewstate if you're using Web Forms, db, session) and will be used when serving subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the current states of your checkboxes (check/uncheck) in querystring, when the page reloads from javascript.

IN C# page load:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString("states")))
{
  SetCheckBoxes(Request.QueryString("states"));
}
```